# Multiple tables or one big one?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In a scenario where I have a table of students all applying for a job and I  want to record where they have applied would it be better practise to create a separate table for each student with their individual applications in or create a separate big table that just links an application to a student?

Comment: Nothing special, just one database.

Comment: Normalization does not state anything about databases at all.

Comment: Your "big" database doesn't even sound very big.

Comment: A database for a student? No way. One database, two tables: Students and Applications

Comment: sorry, changed it to table, also i meant "big" simply as term meaning a collection of all applications not in the sense of it being particularly large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say database do you mean table?

Each noun should map to an entity, which in most cases would be represented by a single table so:

```
STUDENTS-<APPLICATIONS>-JOBS
```

A student can make many applications
An application is made by a single student

An application relates to a single job
One job could have many applications.

```
Students
--------
STUDENT_ID
NAME
...

Applications
------------
APPLICATION_ID
JOB_ID
STUDENT_ID
APPLICATION_DATE
...

Jobs
----
JOB_ID
TITLE
SALARY
...
```

add more columns as required!

Comment: so you're suggesting having 3 tables(not databases, my bad) one for students, application and possible jobs?

Comment: At a basic level that would be what you need:

Answer (score 1):

One 'big' database but with two separate tables.

As long as the business process doesn't change, you shouldn't need to modify the database either. If you have a database per student, you will have to create new databases when you want to enter more students. That already is a signal that you're not doing it right.

Just make a table of students, and a table of student applications, which has a student_id that references a student. That way, you can store as many students as you like, and as many applications per student as you like, with only two tables, without redundant data, and without having to modify the database when you want to file a new record.

And in case you wondered why I put 'big' in quotes: two tables is not much at all, and unless you are going to store every student in your country along with every application they had anywhere, it won't be big in data terms either. A professional database like ProgreSQL can easily manage millions of rows if your database structure is setup properly.

Comment: ah ye fair point about the "big" thing I meant big to mean just a collection of all applications, as i'm sure you gathered. thanks for the clarification tho.

Comment: You're welcome. Some people actually think they should split tables when they reach 1000 records, so I thought it couldn't hurt to mention it. Glad that you aren't one of them. :)

Comment: Are you talking about an Access db? It's fairly common to have 1000000s of records in a table on a proper db e.g. Oracle/SQLServer/Postgres, but then it depends on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'm not talking about any particular DB, but about people who *think* that 1000 records is too much for a single table. Access is not bad either, though. I've seen an example where a (read-only, I admin) Access table of over 40 million records was used by a few hundred people from a networking share. They only searched by the (indexed) curstomer number and got instant results. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Anyway, your avarage student database won't have those numbers, so whichever technology you use, you don't need to split it. Normalizing (storing the applications in a separate table) is a different story, though, and it's good practise to do that, but when I read your answer, I can tell we agree on that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you're talking about a Table, A database is a collection of tables. and a server can hoste multiple databases.

For the question, I think the best answer is to have a table of students, and a table of applications with the students id.

I would really not consider creating a table per students as that will force you to create a table for any new students.